# localhost doesn't open in WAMP 

Tags: php, apache, drupal, wamp

My WAMP server was working fine and I have drupal and another personal php project running in it's www directory. All was fine.

But lately, I tried to configure SVN server with Apache and after that when I try http://localhost
The following code gets downloaded instead of displaying WAMP homepage.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
 * prints the appropriate page.
 *
 * All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
 * See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt.
 */

/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

Also tried opening a static page and it worked. http://localhost/index.html

Comment: something went wrong with my drupal i believe. I'm able to open other PHP projects. But not http://localhost or http://localhost/drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are seeing is the index.php file in the top Drupal directory. Apache should be running it instead of returning it to you. A Google search finds http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/apache/doc/troubleshooting.xml#doc_chap4 which suggests that this is a browser cache problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. Such a elementary thing...but caused havoc!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to ensure apache is configured with the proper `handler` and `module` for interpreting php instead of serving it.

the file IIRC is httpd.conf and chances are high that the module and handler actually listed but commented out